# I get a "-bash: command not found" when trying to use the kaggle API

Tags: python-3.x, terminal, pip, kaggle

I'm trying to use the [kaggle API](https://github.com/Kaggle/kaggle-api) to download competition data with my terminal. When I run the following command

```
$ kaggle competitions download -c titanic
```

I get the following message

```
$ -bash: kaggle: command not found
```

I read that this has to do with the fact that kaggle is probably installed in a binary that is not on the `PATH` variable. To solve my problem I tried to do the following:

```
$ echo $PATH
```

which gives

`/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`

So I tried to find out where kaggle was installed by running

```
$ pip uninstall kaggle
```

which returned

```
Uninstalling kaggle-1.3.9:
Would remove:
/Users/user/Library/Python/3.6/bin/kaggle
/Users/user/Library/Python/3.6/lib/python/site-packages/kaggle-1.3.9.dist-info/*
/Users/user/Library/Python/3.6/lib/python/site-packages/kaggle/*
Proceed (y/n)?
```

I tried adding each one of those binaries to the `PATH` variable by doing

```
$ export PATH=$PATH:~/Users/user/Library/Python/3.6/lib/python/site-packages/kaggle/*
```

for each of them.

However, when I now run `$ kaggle competitions download -c titanic` I still get the same `$ -bash: kaggle: command not found`

Even though `$ echo $PATH` shows that the binaries are now on the `PATH` variable!

**Question:** What can I do to solve this problem and start using the kaggle API? Furthermore, does the fact that pip doesn't install new packages in binaries that are associated with the `PATH` variable mean that I've manually changed something in the past? Or do you need to add those binaries to the `PATH` variable once you start using pip?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you download kaggle.json from https://www.kaggle.com/[account_name]/account

```
pip install kaggle
rm ~/.kaggle
mkdir ~/.kaggle
cp ~/Downloads/kaggle.json ~/.kaggle
kaggle --version
```

Answer (score 0):

I see `kaggle` in `/Users/user/Library/Python/3.6/bin/kaggle` so add `/Users/user/Library/Python/3.6/bin` to `$PATH` and verify `kaggle` is available with `which kaggle`. It it's not — reset `$PATH` cacheing in the shell with `hash -r`.